# .Net - Redis cache "object disposed exception"

Tags: c#, caching, redis

While debugging and locally testing my application, every now and then I get a `"SocketManger.cs" not found` associated with a `System.ObjectDisposedException`. I only get this because on the exceptions settings panel I fully-checked the `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`.

I can't get to the bottom of this problem because i keep pressing `F10`, hoping that one moment, the debugger will take me to the invocation of the read/write operation that is trying to execute on a disposed object. But the moment never comes... I can see in the Call Stack window that i'm going up on the stack, reaching `[External Code]` but I just can't get back to MY CODE...

Since this problem happens regularly, i need to get this done, because this is corrupting my cache or not returning a item that is already cached, forcing my app to duplicate work...

How can i get to the bottom of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you get an ObjectDisposedException? Are you disposing the underlying connection while requests might be going on? Are you doing something like this (https://gist.github.com/JonCole/925630df72be1351b21440625ff2671f#reconnecting-with-lazyt-pattern) where you will need to handle the ObjectDisposedException? YOu should be able to retry in that case.